# MySQL table page not loading correct data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm creating a table that uses PHP to pull from a MySQL database that I have.  I think I've got everything where I want it to be, however the only problem I'm having is that the results seem to be (for lack of a better word) "behind".  What I mean by that is that my first page `index.php` is where I'm accepting user edits to the database.  Once they click `Update` it sends them to my `results.php` file that is supposed to actually perform the SQL UPDATE and then display the updated table.

It updates the table just fine according to XAMPP's database editor.  However, when I said "behind" I mean that the page loads, updates but doesn't display the updated data until either the user refreshes the page or returns to the first page THEN comes back.  I'm not sure what could be causing it, so I'm hoping someone here can help me.  I feel like the reason is something as simple as I'm just running the code in the wrong order, but I don't know for sure.  My code is below:

### index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        include('dbconnect.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_events";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        ?>

        <form name="form1" method="post" action="results.php">
            <table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Event ID</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Event Date</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Speaker</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Building</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Room</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <?php                    
                    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <input name="event_id[]" type="hidden" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $rows['event_id']; ?>">
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['event_id'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input name="title[]" type="text" id="title">
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['topic_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['topic_description']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input name="date[]" type="date" id="date">
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input title="Use reference tables below to enter speaker ID" name="speaker[]" type="text" id="speaker">
                    </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <input title="Use reference tables below to enter building ID" name="building[]" type="text" id="building">
                    </td>


                    <td align="center">
                        <input title="Use reference tables below to enter Room ID" name="room[]" type="text" id="room">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Update" value="UPDATE"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### results.php

```
<html>
    <body>

        <?php
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors',1);

        require_once('dbconnect.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_events";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            $id = $_POST['event_id'];
            $title2 = $_POST['title'];
            $date2 = $_POST['date'];
            $speaker2 = $_POST['speaker'];
            $building2 = $_POST['building'];
            $room2 = $_POST['room'];

            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
                $sql="UPDATE events SET title='$title2[$i]', event_date='$date2[$i]', speaker='$speaker2[$i]', building='$building2[$i]', room='$room2[$i]' WHERE event_id='$id[$i]'";
                $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
            <table width="auto" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Event ID</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Title</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Event Date</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Speaker</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Building</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Room</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <?php                    
                    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['event_id'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['title']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['topic_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['topic_description']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['event_date']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['speaker_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['building_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php echo $rows['room_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Return" value="Return"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Also** if someone can give me some guidance as to how to run the `htmlspecialchars` function on my arrays within `results.php` I'd really appreciate it.  I've already tried to create a for loop for literally each array but that didn't work.  I've tried using ->

```
<?php 
function htmlspecial_array(&$variable) {
    foreach ($variable as &$value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) { $value = htmlspecialchars($value);  }
        else { htmlspecial_array($value); }
    }
}
```

but that also didn't work, and I've tried using the `array_walk_recursive` but to no avail.  I want to try and do something like W3Schools' example here [W3Schools Form Validation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) towards the bottom of the page where it says `Validate Form Data With PHP` and then gives an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get from the UPDATE query is the number of affected rows in your database. To correctly display the updated data, you need to re-fetch from the database before you generate the HTML. You should rearrange your code in results.php like this:

```
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $id = $_POST['event_id'];
        $title2 = $_POST['title'];
        $date2 = $_POST['date'];
        $speaker2 = $_POST['speaker'];
        $building2 = $_POST['building'];
        $room2 = $_POST['room'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_events";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
            $sql="UPDATE events SET title='$title2[$i]', event_date='$date2[$i]', speaker='$speaker2[$i]', building='$building2[$i]', room='$room2[$i]' WHERE event_id='$id[$i]'";
            $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM vw_events";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Side note: If your data is sensitive, you may want to read about mysqli prepared statement so hackers cannot tamper with your queries.

Regarding your question about htmlspecialchars, see Stackoverflow "Execute htmlspecialchars on a multi level array".

Comment: I appreciate your help.  When I rearrange the code in your suggested manner, it tells me that `count` is an undefined variable which makes sense because I'm basically telling the for loop to go up to the value of a variable that doesn't yet exist.  Is there anything else you can think of? Also I appreciate your suggestions and will definitely look into both mysqli prepared statements and the Stackoverflow "Execute htmlspecialchars on a multi level array"

Comment: I got it to work.  You were right, I just needed to re-fetch the database before actually executing the HTML.  I ended up adding a second query after the UPDATE.  I basically added a second


`$query = "SELECT * FROM vw_events";`
`$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`
`$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

before i do the `while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result) {`

Comment: You are right, I missed the fact that you were updating several records. I don't know what is exactly your front-end, but it is a little unusual to update all the records of a table. For scalability, you should consider posting a list of records ID's and loop through this list, adding the ID as a condition of your update query. That way, if the user happen to update only one or few records, you will save execution time by not looping through thousand of records when your database get bigger.